# Reducing text in a text field

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm working on a view which selects a large text field from another table. (No, not the snapshots.) This table contains an errorlog from the web application that provides access to it. However, this errorlog contains some very long texts which cause the column to be extremely wide.
So I want to select the text field, but *any* word longer than 20 characters must be replaced to the first three, an ellipse (...) and the last three letters. Example:

```
 - System.Web.HttpException: The client
   disconnected. --->
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException:
   Invalid viewstate. Client IP:
   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port: xxxx
   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C;
   .NET4.0E) ViewState:
   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
```

This must become:

```
 - System.Web.HttpException: The client
   disconnected. --->
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException:
   Invalid viewstate. Client IP:
   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port: xxxx
   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C;
   .NET4.0E) ViewState: T89...bla
```

And yes, that first text is extremely wide... Even SO has trouble displaying it correctly. :-)
So, I probably need to do something with regular expressions or whatever. Thus: SELECT REGEX(Something, something, something) FROM MyTable; or whatever.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EllipseTextWords(@Text VARCHAR(MAX), @EllipsedSize INT, @Separator AS VARCHAR(1), @EllipsisLength INT = 3)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Tokens TABLE
    (
        Token VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Text) > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Tokens
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Text, 1, CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Text) - 1)))

        SET @Text = SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Text) + 1, LEN(@Text))
    END

    INSERT INTO @Tokens
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@Text))

    UPDATE @Tokens SET Token = LEFT(Token, @EllipsisLength) + '...' + RIGHT(Token, @EllipsisLength) WHERE Token <> '' AND LEN(Token) > LEN(LEFT(Token, @EllipsedSize))

    DECLARE @Ellipsed VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @Ellipsed = COALESCE(@Ellipsed + @Separator, '') + Token FROM @Tokens 

    RETURN @Ellipsed

END
```

then you coul call the created function

```
SELECT dbo.EllipseTextWords(Details, 20, ' ', DEFAULT) FROM ErrorLog
```

but I wonder why dont you do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: I have multiple presentation layers to update. One through a website, another one that calls the data through web services. Some code is written in C# but there's also some Delphi/WIN32 code that connects to the same database. Plus, the long text add a bit more overhead to the record size when sending data over the network.

Comment: I see, of course using stored procedure or function will not be too slow, but it will be surely slower than doing it in the presentation layer, although i agree with you about the network traffic annoyance generated by large text data

Comment: The network traffic could become quite bad since this log table could have 1000+ records, each with a long text in it. System and network are both a bit older and slow so I need to get some performance from it somewhere. Stripping overhead at the server would reduce the total size to about 75% so that's a plus. The multiple presentation layers are the biggest problem, though. There should have been a middle layer and some do share a middle layer. Just not all... Biggest problem is when two or more different app requests all records, thus nearly DOS'sing the server...

Answer (score 1):

How about the following solution. Assuming your table containing the errorlog is called `ErrorLog` and has a column `Details` which holds the large text you're referring to.

1. Create a special function that would split text content into words (took it from [here](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) but essentially any similar function will work):

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
   returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
   as     
   begin
       declare @idx int     
       declare @slice varchar(8000)

       select @idx = 1     
       if len(@String) < 1 or @String is null  return     

       while @idx != 0    
       begin     
          set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter, @String)     
          if @idx != 0     
            set @slice = left(@String, @idx - 1)     
          else     
            set @slice = @String     

          if(len(@slice) > 0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

          set @String = right(@String, len(@String) - @idx)     
          if len(@String) = 0 break     
        end 
        return     
   end
   ```
2. Then retrieve the text field from the ErrorLog table using the query below (basically, it iterates through all words, examines the length of each item and then concatenate them into a new string):

   ```
   SELECT 
   (
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
           (SELECT (CASE WHEN LEN(items) > 50 
                    THEN LEFT(items, 3) + '...'  + RIGHT(items, 3) 
                    ELSE items
                    END) + ' '
            FROM dbo.Split(ErrorLog.Details, ' ') FOR XML PATH (''))
       ,'&amp;','&')
       ,'&lt;','<')
       ,'&gt;','>')
       ,'&#x0A;',char(10))
       ,'&#x0D;',char(13))
       ,'&#x09',char(9))
    )
   AS Details 
   FROM ErrorLog
   ```

Please note that I use 50 as a threshold value because otherwise it will also cut items like 'System.Web.HttpException' which have length > 20.